# Can't solve mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I've looked everywhere but can't find it, so here goes the bit of php code that just *won't work*:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, username, password, database);
$link2 = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if(!$link){
    echo "error link";
}else{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `user`";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if(!$result){
        echo "error ".mysqli_error($link);
        return;
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        //do things
    }
}
```

The if(!$result) doesn't catch anything, and *yet*, I *keep* getting "mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in" errors on the "while" line.

Why?

--EDIT:

A var_dump of $result returns:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(9)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(588)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

$mysqli_error($link) is empty

And I also don't think this is a duplicate, I've looked all over StackOverflow and other forums for this and all of them fail to solve my problem, saying that $result must be returning false due to a failure of the query or something, which is clearly not the case, as shown above.

Comment: Otherwise `var_dump` your `$result` variable, and print out `mysqli_error()` regardless of it.

Comment: Editted to show that.

Comment: Well then it's probably not a duplicate. Still unanswerable though. The warning doesn't match up with your code and the actual variable contents. Show the real code.

Comment: That is the entire code; the only thing that comes after the "while" is an echo, the only thing that comes before the $link is whether the file exists. However, removing the $link2 variable solved it.

Comment: Probably there is something happening in `// do things` that is modifying `$result`, but we can't tell without seeing your code.  Does that loop execute at all?  Have you put a diagnostic in the loop to see?